# Lots of Mac Sierra "Service only ran for 0 seconds" log errors

Tags: macos

My computer is occasionally freezing and in trying to find out why I've found these errors in my console log. There are a LOT of them. Can anyone tell me why, what it means and if it's related to my computer freezing?

```
Dec 15 01:12:55 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:13:19 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:13:19 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78383]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:13:25 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:13:49 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:13:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78392]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:13:55 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:14:20 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:14:20 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78399]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:14:25 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:14:51 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:14:51 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78405]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:14:55 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:15:21 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:15:21 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78412]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:15:26 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:15:52 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:15:52 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78419]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:15:56 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:16:22 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:16:22 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78426]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:16:26 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:16:53 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:16:53 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78432]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:16:56 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:17:24 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:17:24 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78439]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:17:26 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:17:38 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 15 01:17:38 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Dec 15 01:17:46 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:17:54 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78449]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:17:56 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:18:25 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:18:25 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78456]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:18:26 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:18:55 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:18:55 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78462]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:18:56 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:19:26 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:19:26 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78469]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:19:26 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:19:56 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:19:56 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:19:57 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78477]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:20:06 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:20:27 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:20:27 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78484]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:20:36 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:20:58 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:20:58 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78491]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:21:07 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:21:07 bens syslogd[50]: ASL Sender Statistics
Dec 15 01:21:17 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:21:28 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 15 01:21:28 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78497]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:21:37 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:21:59 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:21:59 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78505]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:22:07 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:22:30 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:22:30 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78511]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:22:37 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:23:00 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:23:00 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78518]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:23:07 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:23:24 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 15 01:23:24 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[78523]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Dec 15 01:23:27 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:23:31 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78525]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:23:37 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:24:01 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:24:01 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78535]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:24:07 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:24:32 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:24:32 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78541]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:24:37 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:25:03 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:25:03 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78548]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:25:07 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:25:33 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:25:33 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78554]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:25:37 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:26:04 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:26:04 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78562]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:26:07 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:26:34 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:26:34 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78568]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:26:37 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:27:05 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:27:05 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78575]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:27:08 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:27:35 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:27:35 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[78581]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Dec 15 01:27:36 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78582]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:27:38 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:28:06 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:28:06 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78590]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:28:08 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:28:37 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:28:37 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78597]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:28:38 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:29:07 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:29:07 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78604]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:29:08 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:29:38 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:29:38 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:29:38 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78611]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:29:48 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:30:09 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:30:09 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78620]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:30:18 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:30:39 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:30:39 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78628]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:30:48 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:31:08 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:31:08 bens syslogd[50]: ASL Sender Statistics
Dec 15 01:31:10 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78636]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:31:18 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:31:40 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:31:40 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78649]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:31:46 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[78650]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Dec 15 01:31:48 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:32:11 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:32:11 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78657]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:32:18 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:32:41 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:32:41 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78664]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:32:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:33:11 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:33:11 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78670]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:33:19 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:33:42 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:33:42 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78677]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:33:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:34:12 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:34:12 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78686]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:34:19 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:34:43 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:34:43 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78693]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:34:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:35:14 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:35:14 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78699]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:35:19 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:35:44 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:35:44 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78706]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:35:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:35:57 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[78709]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Dec 15 01:35:59 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:36:15 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 15 01:36:15 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78714]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:36:19 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:36:45 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:36:45 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78721]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:36:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:37:16 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:37:16 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78727]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:37:19 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:37:47 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:37:47 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78734]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:37:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:38:17 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:38:17 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78741]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:38:19 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:38:28 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Dec 15 01:38:29 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:38:48 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 15 01:38:48 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78749]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:38:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:39:18 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:39:18 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78755]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
Dec 15 01:39:20 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.nowplayingtouchui): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Dec 15 01:39:49 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec 15 01:39:49 bens com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.bsd.dirhelper[78762]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.dirhelper
```

Comment: It seems to occur on any version of Sierra. I have it happening on 10.12.2 and 10.12.3 - two completely different setups, but both MacBook Pro's. Some postings seem to suggest that it is related to the Touch Bar on the most recent MacBook Pro's. Somehow this process crashes continuously on MacBook Pro's from earlier generations.

Comment: @pixelearth Did you find a solution to the freezing issue? I have started seeing applications freeze for 5+ seconds at a time and haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @intgr I have contacted Apple Support. No real help except for telling me to  boot in safe mode, and a bunch of other remedies that just don't help. They insist I have installed a driver that causes this issue. I insist it is a macOS issue introduced since macOS Sierra. I am seeing it clearly happening on 2 of my MacBook pro's, once very recent (right before the touchbar release, and one 2011 model). It is draining my battery too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just posting an update to this question. The problem only got worse before it has finally disappeared.

My computer hasn't crashed with errors like these for about 3 weeks now, whereas it was crashing every couple of days before so I'm going to consider the problem solved.

I'm not sure exactly what solved it. But to the best of what I can determine the problem was caused by NOT ENOUGH HARD DRIVE SPACE. I probably had about 15G free (on a 250G drive) and I thought that was enough. But once I made about 50G available, the problem has gone.

I don't know definitively if this is the solution/problem, but it fits enough for me. So if anyone is having similar issues, perhaps this will help. Good luck!

Comment: Same problem for me, and I also had around 15G or 20G free.

Answer (score 5):

Until Apple fixes this one, a workaround is to move the file `com.apple.NowPlayingTouchUI.plist` out of `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/` (after disabling `SIP`). This command will move the file to your home directory:

`$ sudo mv /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.NowPlayingTouchUI.plist ~`

Logout/login for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Something is causing the job to be relaunched. The default ThrottleInterval is 10 seconds, so relaunching it within 10 seconds causes it to fail to launch to save startup costs.

You can find out why the job was launched using `launchctl print` and examining the output for the ‘event triggers’ section.

```
# launchctl print gui/userid/identifier
$ launchctl print gui/501/com.apple.nowplayingtouchui
…
    event triggers = {
        kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingApplicationDidRegister => {
            state = 0
            service = com.apple.nowplayingtouchui
            stream = com.apple.notifyd.matching.501
            monitor = com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua
            descriptor = {
                "Notification" => "kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingApplicationDidRegister"
            }
        }
    }
…
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a Bug(I sent to Apple) related to Sierra and the new touch bar designs for recently released McBookPros, It's from Core services trying to implement the "TouchBarUserInterface" that's "non existent" in all Macs that do not have the bar installed. not harmful but constant system non stop log entries that can be quite annoying......unrelated to Freezing computers

Comment: What I do see is at the same time a `com.apple.ReportCrash` process that constantly pops up in an endless loop, causing apparent freezes, and drains my battery, overheats cpu, causes fan to rev up (really annoying).

Comment: I posted a quick answer here, with a typo, and that answer was deleted by a mod, stating I need to add it as a comment, oh-hum.  It seems that it was bug like your stated and that it has been fixed by apple. I have installed macOS 10.12.4 (16E195) and it has been fixed and has not returned.

The solution now is to update from pre macOS 10.12.4 to macOS 10.12.4

Comment: I have the problem on a mac air early 2014 and it's on MacOS 10.12.5 .  So I don't think this is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to shut up, I've found that running [Touche](https://red-sweater.com/touche/) will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal run:

```
cd /System/Library/LaunchAgents/
sudo rm com.apple.touchbar.agent.plist
```

You need to disable SIP first though...

Comment: Where do you run this? A little more information explaining what is going on and how this fixes the problem would greatly improve your answer.